# FFmpeg can't run in some device Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-x86

i'm working in a video processing project and now i'm using [ffmpeg](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library in Android. I'm facing with a strange problem with asus zenphone 4 t00l (or all x86 device, I've just test in this x86 phone). When start command in project, app always crash:

```
03-30 15:08:18.461 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa I/FFmpeg: Loading FFmpeg for armv7-neon CPU
03-30 15:08:18.781 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa I/System.out: Success........
03-30 15:26:12.933 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 59
03-30 15:26:12.933 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 63
03-30 15:26:15.913 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa D/VideoActivity: onDestroy
03-30 15:26:18.993 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa I/FFmpeg: Loading FFmpeg for armv7-neon CPU
03-30 15:26:19.263 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa I/System.out: Success........
03-30 15:26:42.583 21068-21184/com.paditech.videa D/FFmpeg: Running publishing updates method
03-30 15:26:42.583 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 59
03-30 15:26:42.583 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 85
03-30 15:26:42.683 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa D/VideoActivity: /data/data/com.paditech.videa/files/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: '�4�' unexpected
03-30 15:26:42.683 21068-21068/com.paditech.videa D/VideoActivity: /data/data/com.paditech.videa/files/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: '�4�' unexpected
```

**First**, I think the problem is ffmpeg library. So I created a test module with simple activity just load and run command and there're no problem.

**Second**, I'm afraid that app cannot load version ffmpeg, because in my log, it's armv7-neon althought it's x86 (In my test module, it display x86). And according my search result, may be a external library make app to use abi arm (Build.CPU_API="armv7"). So I try remove all library in gradle in module Test and detected a library. But check in aar file of library, it support all x86 and arm. But after remove it, app still crash with same log. And strangely, althogh Test module register as arm but it'still run success (External question: Why add library jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations make system register as armv7 although it's x86)

**Finally**, i think problem is command. But after debug, I use same command for Test module but it still success. Now i'm still stuck with it. Could anyone help me to solve it. Thanks. Here my demo code:

```
    String input = "/storage/emulated/0/Videa/Video/VIDEO_20160122_160020.mp4";
    String output = "/storage/emulated/0/Videa/Audio/AUDIO_20160330_142501.wav";
    String[] command = {
            "-y",
            "-i",
            input,
            "-vn",
            "-f",
            "wav",
            output
    };
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                super.onSuccess(message);
                System.out.println("Success " + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                super.onFailure(message);
                System.out.println("Failure " + message);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is Failed command:

```
    ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmd.add("-y");
    cmd.add("-i");
    cmd.add(input);
    cmd.add("-vn");
    cmd.add("-f");
    cmd.add("wav");
    cmd.add(output);
    String[] result = new String[cmd.size()];
    return cmd.toArray(result);
```

Comment: Most x86 Android device are capable of using ARM native libraries because of an emulation layer called libhoudini. It's possible that NEON instructions are not supported in this mode, however.

Comment: NEON instructions are supported. The issue here is the emulation layer which got confused because of the architecture of the app, which presented a conflict between the architecture of the libs installed, and the ffmpeg binary that is supposed to run. @tqn  You can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app&hl=en to see what libs are getting installed on the device. You may have to remove and reinstall the app so the /data app directory is clean - maybe the wrong ffmpeg binary stays across updates.